# Database structure for common coupled words

Tags: database, data-structures

I need to create a database to store "*most common coupled words*".
I will feed my software a huge set of texts (books and articles mainly), separate them into paragraphs and store them in some way.
After that, the user should be able to search for a word and check what other words appear the most inside a paragraph with the searched word.

Example: the user search for "flower" and the system should return something like the following.

```
Search word: "flower"

Most common matches with "flower":
1. "red" appeared 4918 times in a paragraph with "flower"
2. "white" appeared 3502 times in a paragraph with "flower"
3. "fresh" appeared 2501 times in a paragraph with "flower"
4. "scented" appeared 2499 times in a paragraph with "flower"
...and so on
```

What's the best database structure to achieve such a functionality with decent speed queries and small storage needs?

Could it be one single tables with sorted words couples and appearence count? Is it better a 2 tables approach for storing words, words_id and a second table to store word1_id, word2_id, count?
Is there another common approach to such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against storing pairs. This would lead to quadratic space complexity. If your paragraphs are 100 words long, then there are roughly 5,000 word pairs, so you would store 5,000 records instead of just 100 -- a 50-fold increase. Rather, you could have a `word` table and a `text_index` table whose purpose is to map words to paragraphs. Something like this:

```sql
create table word (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  form varchar(100) not null default '',

  primary key (id),
  unique key (form)
);

create table text_index (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  word_id int not null default 0,
  paragraph_id int not null default 0,

  primary key (id),
  key (paragraph_id),
  key (word_id)
);
```

In this minimalist example, parahraph IDs would be generated sequentially as you scan the texts. You can certainly refine this, for example by adding a `document` table with document IDs and mapping paragraphs to documents if you need the ability to trace paragraphs back to books.

The query basically says "give me all the words and word counts that share a paragraph ID with 'flower'":

```sql
select w.form, count(*) as c
from text_index a
join text_index b on a.paragraph_id = b.paragraph_id
join word w on b.word_id = w.id
where a.word_id = 1
  and b.word_id != 1
group by b.word_id;
```

Here is some sample data to play with. I haven't tested the query on large data sets, but with proper indexes it should be fast.

```sql
insert into word (form)
values
  ('flower'),
  ('toy'),
  ('candle'),
  ('red'),
  ('white'),
  ('fresh'),
  ('scented');

insert into text_index (word_id, paragraph_id)
values
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 4),
  (2, 5),
  (2, 6),
  (3, 7),
  (4, 1),
  (4, 2),
  (4, 2),
  (4, 2),
  (4, 3),
  (5, 1),
  (5, 4),
  (5, 8),
  (6, 1),
  (6, 2),
  (7, 4),
  (7, 7);
```

Comment: Din't think about such a solution. It sounds interesting, thanks. I'll dig it and make some tests.